# Play entire website in different screen html

Tags: html, screen-size

I had a query and being new to web I have no clue how to go along with it.The question is for example the below given image url in such an image size the entire website should play in it automatically.
Is it possible in html or is it done in flash?
Or how should i go along with it.
    Please guide me through.
[Image url below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMZqf.png)

Comment: just like if a website was in the iMac screen and user will be able to scroll click on website, that's right?

Comment: @LouisBarranqueiro Yes exactly

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer your question. Anyway, I created this demo in `Google Chrome`. If you run this demo via other browser, you maybe will see the scroller outside from the screen. I recommend to use custom scroll like http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/scrollbar_themes_demo.html

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
}
html,
body {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
#page-wrap {
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMZqf.png) no-repeat;
    width: 486px;
    height: 464px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px 36px 186px 20px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.outer {
    background: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
  transform:translateY(0);
  transition:all 4s ease;
}

.inner:hover {
    transform:translateY(-90%);
}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrap">
   <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner">
         <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
         <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
         <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Update**
I was removed the scrollers and add `scroll` animation on mouse hover like you ask. (like: http://themeforest.net/item/panacea-medical-parallax-responsive-wp-theme/full_screen_preview/6441619?ref=freshdesignweb).

Pay attention that the animation is in `css3` only and works on all modern browsers (and some old too..)

Comment: But can I fit in the small size like that image I provided if a website was in the iMac screen and user will be able to scroll click on website?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you meaning by `scroll click`. Also, as you can see in this example, no matter what the screen resolution is, the image is covering the whole page.

Comment: If you see the above image url I have provided in that you see an image which is a desktop pc and on its screen you can see the hand browsing the iMac.The same way I want the entire website to be played inside the desktop pc image in place of the hand browsing the IMac.That's what i want.

Comment: Just one more question: `the entire website` is the same website or you want to show a different website. For example: your domain is `domain.com` and you want to show "inside" the PC screen the website `domain.net`. Right?

Comment: I want to show the same website that is if my website is domain.com then domain.com should be shown inside the pc

Comment: I just was updated my code. Hopefully, now I understand you correctly.

Comment: Ya this is exactly what I wanted so I want the website to placed inside it.Will try doing that.Thank you so much.

Comment: My pleasure. If it was answer your question please mark it as accepted so ןt will help to other people.

Comment: How can I incorporate the entire website inside the image.I mean the script and exact look of the website ?

Comment: I'm not actually understand the problem. In the snippet I was showed how to display an html "in" the image. In this html you can write a header with menu, the content section and the footer - in short, entire website. Your website it's a regular website, so, you can place the scripts wherever you want.

Comment: I have done that but the entire website is giving a horizontal and vertical scroll its not containing in the website

Comment: Can you update the question and add a snippet (or link to a fiddle, snippet is better) with your code? Because, still, I don't understand the problem.

Comment: http://themeforest.net/item/panacea-medical-parallax-responsive-wp-theme/full_screen_preview/6441619?ref=freshdesignweb       I want something similar to this.

Comment: A. you have that the width of the website inside the image will be the same as the width of the content inside the image.If so, you shouldn't see horizontal scroller (Just like in my code). B. Are you want the the vertical scroller will by hidden and on `mouseover` the content will be scroll like the link?

Comment: Yes that's what I require both A and B no scrolls should be seen.Thank you so much

Comment: I just was updated my answer and the snippet. Let me know if you success.

Comment: Ok will check and get back to you soon.You are very kind.Thank you.